# Why would a three phase motor suddenly change it's rotating direction?

Tags: motor, three-phase

A pump is run by a three phase motor, after a voltage fluctuation suddenly the motor starts moving in the reverse direction. However, the motor is connected with a single magnetic conductor for rotation in one direction. How could the motor rotate in the opposite direction? How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You probably don't have all three phases connected correctly - maybe one has an intermittent or broken connection.

Comment: Please explain magnetic conductor in this question.

Comment: Wild guess: each phase has one fuse or breaker, and one of them is blown. (that arrangement would suck, but I've seen it)

Comment: Is the power source the utility power line or some type of electronic drive (VFD or inverter)?

Comment: To prevent damage to the pump fit a one-way clutch between the motor and the pump, then if it does change direction at least it won’t damage the pump...

Comment: It might just be possible IF a single phase is lost, and IF the load began to spin the motor opposite its normal direction during the power outage.  The reason we use three phase motors is that the direction of rotation is constant.

Comment: Add schematic and possibly photo.

Answer (score 5):

You blew a fuse somewhere ahead of this pump and are now giving it single phase power. A 3 phase motor will not start with single phase power, but it will run if started some other way. Your pump likely does not have a check valve to prevent water from flowing backward, so when it is off, there is a slight back-flow spinning it backward, even if only slightly and when you energize it with the single phase power, it is already turning the wrong direction, so it continues to do so.

Find and replace the blown fuse.

Comment: ...and if this is indeed the case, replacing the fuses with a proper 3-phase breaker would be a good idea...

Comment: Right, this sort of situation is exactly why overcurrent protection should interrupt all phases. Fuses can't do that, so breaker.

Answer (score 4):

One of the wires in the conduit could be shorting out causing the reverse I have seen this happen or internally in the motor though rare it's happens.